# Почему в сообщениях беседы при загрузке gif-файла скрипт отправляет "Пустое сообщение" при наличии аттачмента?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, sendmessage

GIF парсится с сайта Pikabu. По поводу сохранения документа вопросов нет, через API они загружаются в мои Файлы:

[image: список загруженных документов по api]

Проблема возникает на этапе отправки сообщения.
Вот данные загруженного документа:

[image: ответ на запрос docs.save]

Вот параметры запроса на message.send и даже получаю response с ID сообщения.

[image: параметры для messages.send и ответ]

Но в сообщениях в беседе присылается пустое сообщение:

[image: пустое сообщение беседы]

внутри которого вообще ничего нет:

[image: пустое сообщение]

Что я делаю не так? Подскажите?

Притом, что таким же макаром загружаются видео, в аттачмент всё добавляется, в беседе всё корректно отображается. А вот gif всё никак не поддается...

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Каким методом получаете сервер для загрузки? [docs.get**Messages**UploadServer](https://dev.vk.com/method/docs.getMessagesUploadServer), да?